# C++ Understanding recursive function

Tags: c++

I need some help with understanding this recursive function. It is returning `101` when `n` = `5` but I do not understand why. Here is the function:

```
string RecursiveMystery(int n) {
  string s = "1";
  if (n % 2 == 0) {
    s = "0";
  }
  if (n < 2) {
    return s;
  }
  return RecursiveMystery(n / 2) + s;
```

So when `RecursiveMystery(5)`, it should go into the end return function `RecursiveMystery(5 / 2)` which is equal to `0` + `1` which is `01` (because `s` = `1` at the time of `RecursiveMystery(5)`). I'm stuck with understanding how it is still returning `101`.

Comment: Try to step in with a debugger, and you'll understand what's going on. There are 3 calls, with parameters: 5, 2 and 1. Only one is even, so the output is `101` (if printed)

Comment: You should read about tail recursion - http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6230/what-is-tail-recursion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call `RecursiveMystery(5)`, it returns `RecursiveMystery(2) + "1"`. So we have to evaluate `RecursiveMystery(2)`, which returns `RecursiveMystery(1) + "0"`. And `RecursiveMystery(1)` returns `"1".

Therefore

`RecursiveMystery(5) = RecursiveMystery(2) + "1" = RecursiveMystery(1) + "0" + "1" = "1" + "0" + "1" = "101"`

Some more infos about the `RecursiveMystery`-method. It computes the binary representation of the number `n`. Basically it writes a `1` at the end, if `n` is odd, and a `0`, if `n` is even. And `n/2` is just the number `n` without the last digit (in binary representation ).

Comment: Since RecursiveMystery(2) returns a "0" wouldn't it be 01 since you can't add strings like you would int? Therefore shouldn't the return value be 01 (just for RecursiveMystery(2) + "1").

Comment: `RecursiveMystery(2) = RecursiveMystery(1) + "0" = "10"`

Answer (score 1):

#### Stage 1:

Run the function with the different inputs you need to see what the results are:

```
RecursiveMystery(5)
    return RecursiveMystery(2) + "1";   // Gets to recursive call

// So look at what RecursiveMystery(2) does
RecursiveMystery(2)
    return RecursiveMystery(1) + "0";   // Gets to recurive call

// So look at what RecursiveMystery(1) does
RecursiveMystery(1)
    return "1";                         // Return early as n < 2
```

#### Stage 2

So now lets expand the top level manually

```
    RecursiveMystery(5)
        return RecursiveMystery(2) + "1";

=>   RecursiveMystery(5)
        return RecursiveMystery(1) + "0" + "1";

=>   RecursiveMystery(5)
        return "1" + "0" + "1";

=>   RecursiveMystery(5)
        return "101";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function starts out at `5`, and keeps `s` as "1", then calls recursively with `n = 2`, and turns `s` to `"0"`, then calls itself recursively one more time (because `2` is *not* below `2`), with `n` as `1`. And this time it's the last call, with `s` remaining `"1"`.

Unwinding the calls back to the original one, you get `"1"+"0"+"1"`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to return "01"  change the if statement

from

```
if (n < 2)
```

to

```
if (n <= 2)
```